# changing raspbian smtp to send via Hotmail NOT gmail?

Tags: sendemail

I feel uncomfortable sending out emails from my Pi via gmail but can't see how to change /etc/ssmtp/ssmtp.conf  to use hotmail instead.

Anyone done this please and if so could I see the /etc/ssmtp/ssmt.conf layout you used. I installed https://trustfoundry.net/honeypi-easy-honeypot-raspberry-pi/

the ssmtp.conf file currently looks like the one below

```
# The user that gets all the mails (UID < 1000, usually the admin)
root=username@gmail.com

# The mail server (where the mail is sent to), both port 465 or 587 should be acceptable
# See also https://support.google.com/mail/answer/78799
mailhub=smtp.gmail.com:587

# The address where the mail appears to come from for user authentication.
rewriteDomain=gmail.com

# The full hostname.  Must be correctly formed, fully qualified domain   name or GMail will reject connection.
hostname=yourlocalhost.yourlocaldomain.tld

# Use SSL/TLS before starting negotiation
UseTLS=Yes
UseSTARTTLS=Yes

# Username/Password
AuthUser=username
AuthPass=password
AuthMethod=LOGIN

# Email 'From header's can override the default domain?
FromLineOverride=yes
```

Comment: First, what package did you install to get `/etc/ssmtp` - it's not part of the base install of raspbian, so you must've installed something to get that - second, what is the current content of ssmpt.conf?

Comment: hi @JaromandaX thank you for taking an interest. I have updated the question to provide clarification.

Comment: Hello. Obvious question but have you tried replacing the "gmail" parts in the configuration with the [Hotmail settings](https://www.lifewire.com/what-are-windows-live-hotmail-smtp-settings-1170861)? If you did, why not show us that instead (without your password!) and include the errors you get.

Comment: @RogerJones  hello back.  Jaromanda asked for what existed and that's what I posted.  I WAS hoping that someone else had trodden this path but seems I am the only paranoid one :-) You make fair points and the answers are YES I tried the hotmail settings ( thanks for the link I did know them before but very helpful) and NO I didn't record the errors.  I will do so this weekend.

Answer (score 0):

> ssmtp has been deprecated in Debian Buster.

I used this configuration which worked.  I needed to change `ssmtp.conf` and `revaliases`

### ssmtp.conf

```
root=yourname@hotmail.com

mailhub=smtp.office365.com:587

rewriteDomain=hotmail.com

AuthUser=yourname@hotmail.com

AuthPass=your_password

UseSTARTTLS=YES

hostname=raspberrypi.localdomain

FromLineOverride=YES
```

### revaliases

```
root:yourname@hotmail.com
```